# Building Hyperlink fields in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a dataTable and then linking it to GridView on my ASP.NET webPage, There are two columns in this GridView, I want 2nd Column to be displayed as hyperLink Field. Here is the Code

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable SearchTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn Title = new DataColumn("Title", typeof(System.String));
    DataColumn url = new DataColumn("url", typeof(System.String));
    SearchTable.Columns.Add(Title);
    SearchTable.Columns.Add(url);
    DataRow ResultRow = null;


    var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/"));
    var accountKey = "MyKey";

    // the next line configures the bingContainer to use your credentials.
    bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

    // now we can build the query
    var webQuery = bingContainer.Web(this.txtSearch.Text, null, null, null, null, null);

    var webResults = webQuery.Execute();

    foreach (var result in webResults)
    {


        ResultRow = SearchTable.NewRow();
        ResultRow["Title"] = result.Title;
        ResultRow["url"] = result.Url;  //I want this Field as a HyperLink

        SearchTable.Rows.Add(ResultRow);
    }

    grdResult.DataSource = SearchTable;
    grdResult.DataBind();


}
```

Any idea that how could i make "Url" field as a hyperLink Field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable SearchTable = new DataTable();
DataColumn Title = new DataColumn("Title", typeof(System.String));
DataColumn url = new DataColumn("url", typeof(System.String));
SearchTable.Columns.Add(Title);
SearchTable.Columns.Add(url);
DataRow ResultRow = null;


var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/"));
var accountKey = "MyKey";

// the next line configures the bingContainer to use your credentials.
bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

// now we can build the query
var webQuery = bingContainer.Web(this.txtSearch.Text, null, null, null, null, null);

var webResults = webQuery.Execute();

foreach (var result in webResults)
{


    ResultRow = SearchTable.NewRow();
    ResultRow["Title"] = result.Title;
    ResultRow["url"] = result.Url;  //I want this Field as a HyperLink

    SearchTable.Rows.Add(ResultRow);
}

grdResult.DataSource = SearchTable;
grdResult.DataBind();
```

This how you Bind title and URL with Grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Title
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%></span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="URL">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    URL
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url")%>" target="_blank">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url")%></a><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Hope this helps. You can also visit this link will give you clear idea about Using Bing API [Buena Digital](http://www.buenadigital.com/blog/2012/05/25/Search-the-web-using-the-new-Bing-API#.T-TzHpH4IWY)

Answer (score 0):

Since your field is of type string, you could add the hyperlink as text:

```
ResultRow["url"] = string.format("<a href='{0}'>{0}</a>", result.Url);
```

You might be better off letting the view handle this and just storing the url:

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='<%# Eval("url") %>'><%# Eval("url") %></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: its showing results like this   <a href='http://www.nokia.de/'></a>, but they are not clickable

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="URL" DataTextField="URLName" runat="server" 
  DataNavigateUrlFields ="URLName"//This must be present
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString ="{0}"/>`

This Should solve your problem or anyone else that has a similar issue